# How to setup HTTPS Mutual Auth between Bluemix and CastIron Virtual Appliance?

Tags: ssl, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

We have tested the Bluemix API Managment taling to OnPremise CastIron Virtual Appliance using http to work fine.
Now we wanted to enable HTTPS and test the same flow using the certificates.
We are not finding the exact steps of how to get this implemented.
Can you give us some steps to be done in BlueMix, Secure Gateway, Secure gateway Client and Castiron Virtual Appliance which we can try out?

We are now using the Virtual Appliance IP set as Destination in Secure Gateway so we are generating certificates using the IP address?
We assume that might cause the issue. Any insights on how to resolve those issues?

Thanks,
Shemida

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if the suggestions in the below link helps ?

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudIntegration/CldInt_StdSC_Install.html#CloudInt_installingsecureconnectors

Comment: It will be good if you can show at least *how* the link would help in your post

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following site for additional information besides Bluemix doc.

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/tag/secure-gateway/

Especially, I feel these articles are relevant to your question.

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/17/securing-destinations-tls-bluemix-secure-gateway/
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/09/24/ibm-secure-gateway-updates-version-130/
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/11/11/secure-gateway-in-production-part1/

I'm not familiar with CastIron Virtual Appliance.  You say you will have an issue with generating certificates with the CastIron Virtual Appliance.  What kind of problem do you have?  Please describe more details.